# Identify patterns based on elements appearing before one element and itself

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame that I would like to reduce it

```
id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
1  s  s  s  w  r  r  t  t  w  s
2  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
3  s  s  s  o  w  w  t  t  o  s
4  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
5  s  s  s  s  s  s  w  w  s  s
6  s  s  s  w  t  t  w  w  w  s
```

the labels are denoted by the following letters: "o", "s", "h", "e", "r", "sp", "ho", "TV", "tr", "trp" and "w"

Based on id I would like to identify letters that occurred before and after w.

Output:

```
1  s  w  r  t  w  s
2  s  o  w  t  o  s
3  s  o  w  t  o  s
4  s  o  w  t  o  s
5  s  w  s
6  s  w  t  w  s
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("s","s","s","s","s","s"), t2=c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),t3 = c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),
                   t4 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t5 = c("r","o","w","o","s","t"), t6 = c("r","w","w","w","s","t"),
                   t7 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"),t6 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"), t8 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t9=c("s","s","s","s","s","s")), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                            6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rle`

```
lst1 <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) rle(x)$values)
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
#  t3  t4  t6  t6.1 t8  t9 
#1 "s" "w" "r" "t"  "w" "s"
#2 "s" "o" "w" "t"  "o" "s"
#3 "s" "o" "w" "t"  "o" "s"
#4 "s" "o" "w" "t"  "o" "s"
#5 "s" "w" "s" NA   NA  NA 
#6 "s" "w" "t" "w"  "s" NA
```

Or if we know the max length before,

```
t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) `length<-`(rle(x)$values, 6)))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(value = rle(value)$values) %>% 
      mutate(colnm = str_c('V', rowid(id))) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
read.table(text = gsub("(.)( \\1)+","\\1",do.call(paste, df[-1])), fill = TRUE)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  s  w  r  t  w  s
2  s  o  w  t  o  s
3  s  o  w  t  o  s
4  s  o  w  t  o  s
5  s  w  s         
6  s  w  t  w  s
```